# Citrix Receiver 13.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, citrix

I tried installing citrix as specified in link below 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

However, as per the last section of the link, KNOWN ISSUES, I am facing too the same issue, i.e., Citrix APPs windows displayed with empty graphics. 
Since, I also login using other OS, I know the the Citrix apps windows which opens up in UBUNTU OS, is correct ( comparing the dimensions of the empty window), however, I am unable to view any graphics. In Plain english, the app window which opens up is empty, transparent and with out any control to display. However, actions like right click double click etc works , but all popup windows within this app is empty too.

I know I can always change to older version, however with older version, I have issues with cursor on the Citrix apps as it keeps on jumping and at times it needs too much patient to work with flickering and jumping mouse all over the screen.

Did someone tried to install Citrix Receiver 13.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with some tweaks to overcome the empty window issue.